# The implementation of a ContentProvider just feels wrong

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, n-tier-architecture

A bit of history: I used to code on main frames with COBOL back in the 90s when top down programming was all that was needed. I then lived through 2-tier, 3-tier and n-tier programming, so I understand abstracting the UI layer from the data layer, but the use of a content provider seems very restrictive and frankly counter intuitive.

I like the concept of abstracting the UI code from the data layer code, but the way the ContentProvider (CP) works seems to break this model. For instance, let's look at an example of an insert/update. Using N-tier, the UI code would call the data abstraction layer with a specific ItemID which would then hand back a POCO for the UI to use. The UI only needed to know about the getters and setters for data binding to work. When it came time to update/insert, the UI code would simply hand the POCO back to the data layer which would then determine if the item needed to be updated or inserted. The UI code didn't need to be concerned with HOW the data got to the DB, only that it either succeeded or failed.

With a CP, the UI code needs to know which URI to use to query based on getting a list of items or a specific item (which I am ok with). But both URIs return a cursor that I have to pass to my POCO which then populates the values so they can be changed by my data binding because cursors can't be updated. Then the UI code must determine whether the POCO needs to be updated or inserted and make a call to the appropriate function again using a specific URI. It then has to build a list of all the fields and all the values that need to be updated as well as providing a selection list to update the DB with.

It seems wrong for the UI layer to have to know about any of these items. Shouldn't all of that be encapsulated within the CP? It really seems to break the abstraction model entirely. What am I missing here with this new fangled technology?

BTW, I've already written an app using a CP so I understand HOW it works, I just don't understand the advantages of WHY it works the way it does. Other than keeping track of changes to data sourced by the CP and automagically updating them in the UI it seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead and programming and the implementation FEELS wrong.

Comment: So whats the coding problem?  Regarding your grievance with ContentProvider, look at Live Data & Room (sqlite specific) https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html which removes boilerplate cursor work and can use reactive extensions for observing data changes.

Comment: It's not a grievance with the CP, I am simply trying to figure out what I am missing about the CP that makes it a viable solution. I'm looking into your link now.

Comment: first you could ask yourself if you really need CPs? do you want to share your app's data to other apps? if all you need is some local db then use `Room` (and/or [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support lib) - but honestly i dont know whats so bad with `Cursor`s - i love them btw (when used with `SimpleCursorAdapter` for example)  ;-)

Comment: The problem is, for the most part, your implementation. The UI layer doesn't need to know anything about the CP, you use separations of concern like MVC, MVP, MVVM etc.. and like @pskink said, unless you're sharing data across processes/apps then your reasoning for using a ContentProvider doesn't make sense.

Comment: I definitely don't want to share data with other apps, so I may be way over engineering things, just to follow current app design. It is my understanding that the CP is the best way to go right now, so perhaps it's my understanding that is flawed. :)

Comment: so take a look at [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support lib - it works quite well even with large data sets

Comment: Does the room architecture support calls from a webservice or is it local DB access only?